# Is there a way for an Australian citizen to retrieve their passport number online?

Tags: passports, australian-citizens

Is there any Australian government website where a citizen who needs their passport number but doesn't have access to their passport can find out their passport number?

I've been looking through government websites but not finding anything so far.

Comment: Do you need it for booking a flight ticket?

Comment: Have you tried looking at old airplane ticket bookings or similar paperwork in your email account?

Comment: @JonathanReez. No I needed it for a non-travel-related purpose, but I still saw a travel.SE question in it that might be useful to others.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Yes I did. None of them included my passport number. And of the old emails about passport updates the only one that did include a number was for a previous passport.

Comment: What about 'visa' websites like the ESTA site? But maybe for other countries you've visited?

Comment: @MarkMayo: In my case I can't think of such a site that I've used... Oh I did have to get a Canadian E(S)TA when I flew from China to Mexico a year ago. I wonder ...

Comment: @MarkMayo: Dude you should add that to your answer and I would upvote it and accept it a second time if I could. My passport number is in email from the Canadian immigration website in my Yahoo mail, which I only use in China because they block Gmail. This might've saved me an hour or two if I'd found it at the time (-:

Comment: @hippietrail jackpot! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only [online portal to view your passport details](https://ppol.passports.gov.au/Web/Doc/EntryPoint.aspx) requires knowing your passport number.  It's not associated with any other ID numbers, so that one piece of info is quite critical. :/

If you used an online portal like ESTA or the Canadian version where you might have submitted it, check that or your email to see if perhaps it's stored there too.

Comment: Yes that's as far as I've got too )-:

Comment: Indeed it was in an email from a year ago when I applied for my Canadian EtA in China. I only checked my Gmail but in that's blocked in China so I used my Yahoo mail there.